# Render React Native Componente defined by JSON

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I came up with an idea of rendering React Native components, for example, defined by a JSON response from a web service.
What i was thinking was having a JSON response like this:

```
{
 component_type : Text, 
 content: "Hello World"
}
```

or, if possible:

```
{
   component: <Text> Hello World</Text>
}
```

and then have a parser to convert this response to an actual Component an render it like this:

```
render(){

 {response.component[0]}

}
```

There is any library that can do this?
I've already searched a lot and didn't found anything like this.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to have a library that attend you the way you want.

I don't think it's a good a idea to send a component text like in the approach #2. It's not a good practise to save the logic of the component in the database.

The first one is better. I have developed an an that we render some forms based on a JSON that we fetch from a web service. It was fully customized by our needs and was inspired in the Swift Library `Eureka`

There is a famous library called `Tcomb form` that creates forms based on a schema: https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-form-native